# Get hasOneThrough value in Laravel and paginate it

Tags: laravel, eloquent, inertiajs

I have the following schema:

[image: schema]

And there are the relations on the models

```php
class Financial extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Request extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function financial() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Financial::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, Financial::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the `User` from the `Request` using the `hasOneThrough` so I wrote this code:

```php
$query = Request::select('*')->has('user')->with(['user' => function ($innerQuery) {
    return $innerQuery->orderBy('id','ASC');
}]);

$requests = $query->paginate(6);
```

But this returns an empty array, if I remove the `has` it does indeed return something, the value of the `Request` with an `User` field which is `null`

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "created_at": "2022-02-21T07:04:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-02-21T07:04:42.000000Z",
    "notes": null,
    "status": "PENDING",
    "financial_id": 2,
    "user": null
  }
```

Am I doing it wrong? I already checked, the DB has stored the records correctly, they have the correct id's and data.

## Edit

This is the SQL output of the query

```php
$query = Request::select('*')->has('user')->with(['user' => function ($innerQuery) {
    return $innerQuery->orderBy('id','ASC');
}]);
dump($query->toSql());
```

output:

With which throws an unknown column error

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, Financial::class, 'user_id', 'financial_id');
}
```

```sql
select * from `requests` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `financials` on `financials`.`id` = `users`.`financial_id` where `requests`.`id` = `financials`.`user_id`)
```

And with:

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, Financial::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

```sql
select * from `requests` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `financials` on `financials`.`id` = `users`.`id` where `requests`.`id` = `financials`.`user_id`)
```

These are the entitites migrations:

financials table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('financials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name')->nullable()->default('');
        $table->string('address')->nullable()->default('');
        $table->string('bank')->nullable()->default('');
        $table->tinyText('description')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

requests table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('notes')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->nullable()->default('PENDING');
        $table->foreignId('financial_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('financials');
    });
}
```

users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

## Edit : Working code:

I played with the `hasOneThrough` params until it generated the correct sql sentence and it was done with this code:

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, Financial::class, 'id', 'id', 'financial_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Which outputs this sql

```sql
select * from `requests` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `financials` on `financials`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `requests`.`financial_id` = `financials`.`id`)
```

but I am kind of confused now with the parameters since this is what the docs says about them:

[image]

Comment: check your query output with `->toSql()` instead of `->paginate()`. Maybe the arguments to your `hasOneThrough` are wrong. Also that `$innerQuery` makes no sense for a single object relation

Comment: fix this code like this: `public function user() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, Financial::class, 'user_id', 'financial_id');
    }`__if not working let us to see your table fields

Comment: if I add the ```financial_id``` in the ```hasOneThrough``` I got this error ```Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.financial_id' in 'on clause'```. I updated the question with the migrations and the sql output. Let me know if you need more info Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a lot misconceptions about `hasOneThrough` and `hasManyThrough` out there.

Those relations are one way ticket there is no reverse, meaning you can use them to go from the **User** to the **request** but you **CAN'T** use them (hasOneThrough in this particutal case) to go from the **request** to the **user**.

This is because `hasOneThrough` will look for a **request_id** in the **financials** table and then for a **financial_id** in the **users** table. The same goes with `hasManyThrough` in case anyone wondering.

The only way to get to the User is by regular `belongsTo` relation.

There are a lot of options if you want to get a specific or many users. some of the them would be the following.

this will return the user of a specific request

```
$user = Request::find( some_id )->financial->user;
```

or if you want to filter the users depending on the requests

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = User::whereHas("financials", function(Builder $query) {
    $query->whereHas("requests", function(Builder $query) {
        $query->where("some_column", "something_to_search");
    });
})->get();
```

the above assumes you have a `financials` relation in your User model which i believe you do since you have a one to many relation with user and financial model.

Comment: Hello sir, I undestand what you are saying but that got me questioning what the proper way of getting this 2-way or more deeper relationship is, I tested this code which is working ```Request::with(['financial' => function ($query) use($id){
            $query->with('user');
        }])->get();``` would this be ok? is there a nice way to get the user as a direct child of ```Request``` so I had not to do ```request.financial.user```?

Comment: @H3lltronik request will never have the user as a direct child since the financials table is between them. Also there is no point executing a query like the one in your comment. You could change it to `Request::with("financial.user")->get()`. This will return everything, all the requests with all the financials and the users